# Background bands and specific labels in Vega Lite

Tags: vega-lite, vega

1 - Im attempting to create a chart which displays 4 sections based on values on each axis (-x,-y)(-x,y)(-y,x)(xy), is there a way to set a separate background colour for each section?
2 - is there a way to add a permanent label to specific data points (text function i believe)

[image]

Tried text function but not sure about background

Comment: Yes, both are possible. For background colour, create a rect mark with the appropriate colour and positional encodings. Similar for the text. In order to assist further, please supply a working spec and a drawing of desired outcome.

Comment: @DavidBacci thank you for the reply, here is a link to the json https://github.com/GeorgeRobbin/GeorgeRobbin.github.io/blob/main/HOUSE_MORTGAGE.json. i have updated the original post with a image of the desired chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "config": {"background": "white", "view": {"stroke": "transparent"}},
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GeorgeRobbin/GeorgeRobbin.github.io/main/Chart2_HPI%3AMR.csv",
    "format": {"type": "csv"}
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Mortgage Rate Annual % Change",
      "scale": {"zero": false},
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"grid": false},
      "title": "Mortgage Rate Annual % Change"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "House Price Annual % Change",
      "scale": {"zero": false},
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"grid": false},
      "title": "House Price Annual % Change"
    },
    "tooltip": [{"field": "Date", "type": "temporal", "title": "Name"}]
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "rect"},
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"x": 0, "y": 0, "x2": -29.9, "y2": -15, "c": "#cfdaef"},
          {"x": -29.9, "y": 0, "x2": 0, "y2": 20, "c": "#ffe9b7"},
          {"x": 0, "y": 0, "x2": 90, "y2": -15, "c": "#dbebd2"},
          {"x": 0, "y": 0, "x2": 90, "y2": 20, "c": "#facfb7"}
        ]
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "x"},
        "y": {"field": "y"},
        "x2": {"field": "x2"},
        "y2": {"field": "y2"},
        "color": {"field": "c", "scale": null}
      }
    },
    {"mark": {"type": "circle", "color": "red", "opacity": 0.7}},
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text"},
      "transform": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "field": "Date",
            "oneOf": [
              {"year": 2022, "month": "jan", "date": 4},
              {"year": 2009, "month": "jan", "date": 3}
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "Date", "type": "temporal"}}
    }
  ],
  "height": 300,
  "width": 500
}
```

Comment: I am attempting a similar chart however the X-axis is temporal rather than quantitative. I have followed the method but cant get it to work. [Link to jSON] https://github.com/GeorgeRobbin/GeorgeRobbin.github.io/blob/main/us_housing_indicators.json

Comment: Please ask a new question as this looks like it is dealing with faceting and I'm really not sure what your result is supposed to look like without a picture as the spec contains errors and contradictions.